# "Paste Into" tool not working

Tags: adobe-indesign

I can't figure out how to use the "paste into" tool, specifically to create what the image displays from [this article](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WSa285fff53dea4f8617383751001ea8cb3f-6f2fa.html).

I'm selecting photo #1 from the target so that the border around the photo is orange, cutting it, selecting the second photo, which is a circle, clicking "paste into", which is supposed to make the image paste into the circle, but the image pastes on top of the circle.

I am very new to this program and would appreciate step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if you already have something inside your "circle". If the circle already contains an image and you are selecting it with the Direct Selection Tool (the white arrow) the same way you are the photo in the rectangle, then paste into will not work. You can't paste into a placed graphic.

These steps should work.

- Select the photo using the DIrect Selection Tool (the white arrow)
- Edit > Copy
- Select the circle using the Selection Tool (The Black Arrow)
- Edit > Paste Into